# How to use Where (in LINQ) to get a specific information

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning OOP while doing some algorithmic tasks. I am going to post the task because there are lots of "challenge guys" who love to solve algorithmic problems.

I made a "Car" class which holds following signature. It has Engine, Cargo and Tire, which are separate classes.

Car class :

```
public Car(string model, Engine engine, Cargo cargo, List<Tire> tires)
    {
        this.Model = model;
        this.Engine = engine;
        this.Cargo = cargo;
        this.Tire = tires;
    }

    public List<Tire> Tire { get; set; }

    public Cargo Cargo { get; set; }

    public Engine Engine { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }
```

Cargo class :

```
public Cargo(int cargoWeight, string cargoType)
    {
        this.CargoWeight = cargoWeight;
        this.CargoType = cargoType;
    }

    public string CargoType { get; set; }

    public int CargoWeight { get; set; }
```

Tire class :

```
 public Tire(double tirePreassure, int tireAge)
    {
        this.TireOneAge = tireAge;
        this.TireOnePreassure = tirePreassure;
    }

    public double TireOnePreassure { get; set; }

    public int TireOneAge { get; set; }
```

In the Cargo class, "cargoType" can be "fragile" or "flamable". The tire class holds tireAge and tirePreassure. I am receive an input which looks like this :

2 (number of cars)

1.ChevroletAstro 200 180 1000 fragile 1.3 1 1.5 2 1.4 2 1.7 4

2.Citroen2CV 190 165 1200 fragile 0.9 3 0.85 2 0.95 2 1.1 1
fragile (cargoType)

I need to print all the cars that their cargoType is fragile and their tirePressure is under 1.

This is my code :

```
        if (command == "fragile")
        {
            var newCars = cars
                  .Where(x => x.Cargo.CargoType == "fragile")
                  .Select(d => d
                  .Tire.Where(x => x.TireOnePreassure < 1.0))
                  .ToList();
        }
```

But this returns List of Tires, and I need List of cars with that specific info.

Full code : http://pastebin.com/wnfckfjV

Task : http://image.prntscr.com/image/8f04ee35b5be4a5d8c24e8cb91e69d02.png

Answer (score 2):

```
if (command == "fragile")
{
    var newCars = cars.Where(x => 
                     x.Cargo.CargoType == "fragile" &&
                     x.Tire.Any(tire => tire.TireOnePreassure < 1.0)
                  ).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should give you what you want:

```
var newCars = cars.Where(c => c.Cargo.CargoType.Equals("fragile") &&
                              c.Tire.Any(t => t.TireOnePresssure < 1.0);
```

You might need to check that `Tire` is not null.